# What are the lightning like flashes near the main parachute of Boeing's Starliner test?

Tags: boeing

Boeing released a highlights real of its test flight, and around 2:30 the main chutes deploy.  When that happens, it appears as though is lightning like flashes around the main chute's cords.  What is causing that?  Video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=171&v=i4CeipvvYb4&feature=emb_logo)

Comment: It looks like the main chute's cords are being illuminated by a blinking light (a safety feature like what various aircraft have). Another cord is violently swaying and when it gets illuminated, it looks like lightning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those "lightning flashes" around the main parachute's cords are actually the cords being illuminated by its blinking strobe lights. Now I can't find a document that specifically says Starliner has strobe lights but there are pictures of Starliner where its parachute cords seem to be illuminated.

[image]

In this video, you can see the strobe lights blinking:

There is also a cord that is violently swaying (it is moving at hundreds of km/h in an atmosphere) and when it gets illuminated by the strobe light, it looks like a lightning bolt.

[image]

The "lightning bolt" that is circled is actually a cord that is swaying and is being illuminated by a strobe light.